# Global plugin in VIM is not loaded

Tags: vim

I love the `dragvisuals` vim plugin introduced in Damien Conway's [OSCON 2013 talk](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=aHm36-na4-4). There is a github clone for the plugin here: https://github.com/atweiden/vim-dragvisuals. The problem is I can't get it to work. Here are the steps that I have taken:

1.Drop the script in my `$VIMRUNTIME/plugin` path and added the relevant settings to my `.vimrc`

```
ru plugin/dragvisuals.vim
vmap  <expr>  <LEFT>   DVB_Drag('left')
vmap  <expr>  <RIGHT>  DVB_Drag('right')
vmap  <expr>  <DOWN>   DVB_Drag('down')
vmap  <expr>  <UP>     DVB_Drag('up')
vmap  <expr>  D        DVB_Duplicate()
let g:dvb_trimws = 1
```

2.The script gets loaded successfully because it is output by `:scriptnames`

```
/vim/runtime/path/dragvisuals.vim
```

But all of the functions (DVB_Drag, DVB_Duplicate) are not loaded. Am I missing anything?

**EDIT:** 
At first I tried putting the script in `~/.vim/plugin` as well as as `~/.vim/bundle/vim-dragsvisual/plugin` because I use `vundle` to manage my plugins. But it didn't work; that's why I put the script in `$VIMRUNTIME` as the last resort.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Start again by placing the plugin in `~/.vim/plugin` and removing the `ru plugin/dragvisuals.vim` from your `~/.vimrc`.

Installed correctly, that plugin seems to work perfectly and does exactly what it's supposed to do, here.

*Never* touch `$VIMRUNTIME`.

Comment: Besides, this maybe a dummy question, but what's the difference between "global" plugin and normal plugin?

Comment: It *should* work if you put it where it is supposed to be. If not, it means that you have another problem in your config.

Comment: There's no such difference. I tried here both in `~/.vim/bundle` (with pathogen) and in `~/.vim/plugin` and both work perfectly.

Comment: That's weird. Yes, the script gets loaded from both `~/.vim/bundle` and `~/.vim/plugin` without problem. But there functions (DVB_*) are not. That's why I thought maybe the problem lies in the word "global", hence the attempt to put it in `$VIMRUNTIME`. I have over 20 plugins installed both manually and through vundle and none introduced any problem.

Comment: Sorry never mind, I'm the biggest idiot on earth. I disabled the arrow keys when I started learning vim and forgot about it. The functions are indeed loaded; I just tried to call them without `:call`.